# The very first question if deleted cannot be retrieved until 2nd question is added

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions

I have noticed one issue that very first question if deleted cannot be retrieved. The steps were:

I asked 1 question today, which was down-voted. I realized that it should have not been asked in Software Engineering site hence deleted that question in order to move it to other site.

Unfortunately I could not retrieve my question any longer. It was not available even in ['recently deleted question' list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/165773). I reported that as bug in meta for Stack Overflow and people thought there is bug in my memory as they too cannot locate that question.

I decided to reproduce that issue. Hence added another question in SE. To my surprise, 1st question which I had deleted earlier started showing up in 'recently deleted question' section once I have added 2nd question.

It seems to me a bug.

Comment: This might just be a caching problem. Many statistics and lists are not updated in real time, but only in regular intervals.

Comment: Probably it was not a caching prob. I had checked from both my laptop and mobile phone. Moreover I was discussing this with a member in SO for about 1 hour. I had closed browser and reopen many times during that discussion.

Comment: Caching on the server side, which SE does *very* aggressively, not caching on the client.

Comment: is this the question you wonder about? [deleted question, visible only to asker and 10K users](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/356731/best-option-to-build-windows-store-app-for-window-10)

Comment: I also wonder, when you posted [the second question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/356738/31260), did system give you warning of any kind, about previous questions not being received well?

Comment: @gnat No. I didn't notice any warning or unusual message while adding 2nd question.

Comment: Don't believe a warning will ever kick in after a single question, @gnat. We might want to change that, but first let's fix this bug - I've reproduced it as well, and found the source of the problem. Note that it works correctly in the mobile theme - there's just a bad choice of conditional block for placing this link in the main theme. [Main meta report of this same bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251800/why-does-deleted-recent-questions-not-appear-for-users-who-have-asked-only-one)

Comment: thank you @Shog9! Fixing this bug indeed seems to be important - per my recollection SO users get throttled for a full day if their first question is poorly received. It would be great if such users could find it even if it was deleted and learn from it and maybe improve. (Side note, speaking of that first-poor-question throttling, do you by chance know why it doesn't seem to happen here at SE.SE, it this intentional?)

Comment: It's a two-question minimum everywhere except Stack Overflow, @gnat. And yes, this bug does make that rather brutal on SO - fortunately, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this. Should be fixed as of about 3 hours ago!

See also: [Why does "deleted recent questions" not appear for users who have asked only one question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251800/why-does-deleted-recent-questions-not-appear-for-users-who-have-asked-only-one)

Comment: Thanks much @Shog9 and team.